# Magento 2: Change "Add to cart" button text to "Item in Cart" when item is added to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I want to rename the add to cart button as soon as the product is added to cart.

Comment: After changing text if customer clicks on button it will re add product to cart. It may be confusing for customer.

Comment: no, i want to add product to the cart only once.

Comment: Okay I will post solution in some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change button text by create **mixin** instead of override whole file.

Create **requirejs-config.js** file :

> **app/code/RH/Helloworld/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
   config: {
       mixins: {
           'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'RH_Helloworld/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixin': true
            }
        },
     }
};
```

Create **catalog-add-to-cart-mixin.js** file :

> **app/code/RH/Helloworld/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui'
],
function ($, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', target, {
            options: {
                addToCartButtonTextAdded: $t('Product Added to Cart'),
                addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding: $t('Product Adding to Cart ...'),
                addToCartButtonTextDefault: $t('Product Add to Cart')
            }
        });

        return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
    };
});
```

Comment: Hey, it works but if i remove item from minicart at that time the button text is not set as default.

Comment: Hi Thanks. It's only for add to cart action Not for minicart action.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Comment: Let me find it. If I will found then I will update it. I think it's different functionality then, current question so, asked it as separate so helpful for others.

Comment: Yes, Sure.  And Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Happy coding !!

Comment: after page load it again set the detault button text. even if the product is in cart

Comment: Yes It's only for action purpose. After page load it will reset.

Comment: i want to keep my given button text if the product is still in cart after page load. any solution for that?

Comment: You need to fetch quote items array and compare product id based on condition and then need to change text in list.phtml file.

Comment: yes i did same. and its working now :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to change **Add To Cart** button text after product is added to cart, you need to override `catalog-add-to-cart.js to` in your custom theme.

Copy `catalog-add-to-cart.js` to your theme from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

and replace `enableAddToCartButton` function with below code

```
enableAddToCartButton: function (form) {
    var addToCartButtonTextAdded = this.options.addToCartButtonTextAdded || $t('Added'),
        self = this,
        addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);

    addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextAdded);
    addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextAdded);

    setTimeout(function () {
        var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Your Custom Text');

        addToCartButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
        addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextDefault);
        addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextDefault);
    }, 1000);
}
```

In above code change `Your Custom Text` to your desired text. Thanks!

Comment: this code works but i want to add product to the cart only once. after that i want not-clickable button. Right now it adds product to cart everytime i click on it., can you please help me with that?

Comment: @Fenashah Add `addToCartButton.attr("disabled", true);` code in the end of **setTimeout** function.

Comment: i tried but after page load it again gets enable and set default button text.

Comment: In that case you may use maximum quantity allowed in the cart configuration.Check this blog for more details https://meetanshi.com/blog/set-minimum-qty-allowed-in-shopping-cart-in-magento-2

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339775/magento-2-change-add-to-cart-button-text-when-item-is-removed-from-the-minica can you help me with this?